# Populate mulitple select box jquery mobile via php

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

I found this link which works with jquery but not with jquery-mobile multiselect

[Link to other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870667/populate-select-box-from-database-using-jquery)

Any ideas where i might be going wrong. As soon as i add multiple="multiple" i get no results showing. Also if i have it missing i dont get the jquery mobile theme but i do get my list populated

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/logout-button.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index4">

           <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide"
         data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
            Back
        </a>
        <h3>
           Event Details
        </h3>
    </div>

         <div data-role="content">
             <form id="eventForm" name="eventForm">

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#index4", function() {
$(function(){
      var items="";
      $.getJSON("event-details.php",function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          items+="<option value='"+item.email+"'>"+item.username+"</option>";
        });

        $("#a1_title").html(items); 
        $("#a1_title").trigger("change");
      });
    });
  });  
</script>
        <select id="a1_title"  multiple="multiple">
        </select>
            </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="manual">Add Emails</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="emails" id="emails"></textarea>
                    </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitEventButton">
                </form>
        </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

my php

```
require_once("../backend/functions.php");
dbconn();
                            $id = $CURUSER["id"];
                            $res = "SELECT email,username FROM users left join cal_contacts on cal_contacts.contactid = users.id WHERE cal_contacts.userid = $id";
                            $res1 = mysql_query($res);
                        $data = array();
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
                            { 
                            $data[] = $row;

                            }
                            echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Sorry it does work but you must use a mobile device not my web browser to select from the list

Comment: $("#a1_title").trigger("change"); does the trick. I have updated the top post

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile is a little bit different the a classic multiple select box.

You didn't do anything wrong, you were lacking one additional attribute. Without it jQuery Mobile multiple select can't be created successfully.

Additional needed attribute is this one:

```
data-native-menu="false"
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dEXac/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new select element    
    $('<select>').attr({'name':'select-choice-1','id':'select-choice-1','multiple':'multiple', 'data-native-menu':'false'}).appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
    $('<option>').html('Select option!').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'1'}).html('Value 1').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'2'}).html('Value 2').appendTo('#select-choice-1');    
    // Enhance new select element
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

One more thing, you don't need to use:

```
$("#a1_title").trigger("change");
```

It is a overkill in your case, you only need to enhance one dynamic select, do it like this:

```
 $('select').selectmenu();
```

To find out more take a look at my other article: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**